# An odd method to initialize delegate variable

Tags: c#

One of the ways to initialize a delegate variable uses the syntax with
 *() { return ...}*  after the delegate variable, e.g.

```
   Action<int> MyAction() { return d1 => { }; }
```

All the sources using such initializations do not include good explanation
of this type of syntax. It looks like a default constructor followed by
object initializer except object initializers do not use "return" but 
field names. Another thing is that this works only for the regular delegate
variables and it does not work for event delegate variables, i.e. this
will not compile

```
   event Action<int> MyAction() { return d1 => { }; }
```

even though a similar way to initialize works for both:

```
Action<int> MyAction1 = d1 => { };
event Action<int> MyAction1 = d1 => { };
```

What is the logic behind such syntax and exception for *event*?

Comment: I don't get your question can you be more clear?

Comment: "One of the ways to initialize a delegate variable uses the syntax with `() { return ...}` after the delegate variable" - no, that's declaring a method that returns a delegate when it's called. It's a method, not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
Action<int> MyAction() { return d1 => { }; }
```

This is not a delegate. It's a method typed to return a delegate instance.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like a default constructor followed by object initializer except object initializers do not use "return" but field names.

This is because it's not an initializer, it's a method that returns an `Action<int>` delegate. Here is the "anatomy" of the method definition:

- Return type is `Action<int>`
- Method name is `MyAction`
- Empty parentheses `()` indicate that the method takes no parameters
- `d1 => { }` is a lambda expression, which is convertible to `Action<int>`
- `return` indicates that the above expression is returned from `MyAction` method

Your other three declarations are parsed as follows:

- `event Action<int> MyAction()` is invalid because of the parentheses. They tell the compiler that you are declaring a method, while `event` keyword tells the compiler it's an event,
- `Action<int> MyAction1 = d1 => { };` is a field of type `Action<int>` initialized using a lambda expression to a delegate that does nothing,
- `event Action<int> MyAction1 = d1 => { };` is an event initialized using a lambda expression to a delegate that does nothing.

Comment: Nit-pick: `d1 => { }` is a lambda expression which is convertible to `Action<int>`. Feel free not to edit, but I thought I'd mention it in case.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the comment! You are always welcome to edit my answers if you find it more expedient than typing up a comment.